# Bar Mean vs Bracket Mean

Tags: notation, average

I know that the standard representation for the average of a data set:
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}^N{x_i}
$$

I have also ran into an average denoted as $\langle x \rangle$. This notation is frequently used in physics, and I understand it to be a continuous average over either time or space:

$$
\langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b{f(x)}
$$

Where $f(x)$ can be a function of any coordinates of space and/or time.

From this there is also the relation as $N \to \infty$ and $\Delta(x_i, x_{\pm i}) \to 0 $:

$$
\bar{x} = \langle x \rangle = \frac{1}{\infty}\sum_i^\infty{x_i} = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^bf(x)
$$

This indicates that given enough samples, it should be the case that $\bar{x}=\langle x \rangle$.

Am I correct in this understanding that $\bar{x}$ represents a discrete average and $\langle x \rangle$ represents a continuous average, or is there something else to this?

Comment: I have also seen the bracket operator to mean expectation. In that case, $\bar{x}$ would be the sample mean and $\langle x \rangle$ the expected value (of a continuous random variable).

Comment: I know of that use of $\langle x \rangle$ as well, and it is used to represent what should be the mean of a set of data from an experiment (in physics at least). Could it just be that generally $\bar{x} = \langle x \rangle$, or something along those lines?

Comment: Well if data is iid, then by the strong law of large numbers, the sample mean converges almost surely to the expectation, i.e., $\bar{x}\to\langle x \rangle$ with probability 1 as $N\to\infty$.

Answer (score 6):

The ISO 80000-2:2009 defines $\bar{x}$ as the "*mean value of $x$*" and $\langle x \rangle$ as the "*arithmetic mean of $x$*". So both notations denote the same object only when the mean is arithmetic. However, usually non-arithmetic means are explicitly denoted --for instance, $\bar{x}_G$, $\tilde{x}$, and $G(x)$ are used for geometric mean--, which means $\bar{x} = \langle x \rangle$ for most practical cases.

All statistics books I have use the bar notation to denote means. But [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mean.html) states that the angle notation is sometimes also used.

Answer (score 0):

For the average of p(t) over T, without calculus I would propose:

$$P = {\left.\overline{p(t)}\right|_0^T}$$

in preference of

$$P = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T p(t)\ d t.$$

The reason being that the integration sign is intimidating for people without a calculus background.

Your comments would be most welcome.